# Disabling warnings in iWork

Tags: macos, pages, keynote, iwork, numbers

Is there any way of disabling the warning popups in the current versions of Numbers, Pages and Keynote that popup when files are opened? For example:

[image]

They are pretty useless warnings, in the sense that they have never changed how I worked with a document in a given session, so was hoping I could simply shut them off. Maybe a hidden preference?

Answer (score 1):

If you save out the files in a Pages format you will not get the errors. You generally only get those errors when trying to open documents from Microsoft Word or something similar. I am pretty sure there is no way to disable the warning though from the preferences or anything.